# My scraper fails to move on after collecting one record

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web-crawler

I've created a script which is able to parse the profile name of every person under view all recommendation tab from the home page of Linked-in. Every time I run my script it only parses a single record then throws an error instead of moving on to the next record.

The error I'm having is:

```
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Here is the full code I've written so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

def linked_in():

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login?goback=&trk=hb_signin')

    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="session_key-login"]').send_keys('email')
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="session_password-login"]').send_keys('password')
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btn-primary"]').click()
    time.sleep(5)

    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class,'feed-s-follows-module__view-all')]").click()
    time.sleep(5)

    for item in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class,'feed-s-follow-recommendation-card__profile-link')]"):
        arranging_items(driver, item.get_attribute("href"))

def arranging_items(driver, name_link):

    driver.get(name_link)


    try:
        for item in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'org-top-card-module__details')]"):
            name = item.find_element_by_xpath(".//h1[@title]")
            title = item.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[contains@class,'company-industries']")
    except Exception:
        pass
    else:
        try:
            for item in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'pv-top-card-section__information')]"):
                name = item.find_element_by_xpath(".//h1[contains(@class,'pv-top-card-section__name')]")
                title = item.find_element_by_xpath(".//h2[contains(@class,'pv-top-card-section__headline')]")
        except Exception:
            pass
    finally:
        try:
            print(name.text, title.text)
        except Exception:
            pass

    driver.quit()

linked_in()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's explore the code flow here:

- when you do `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class,'feed-s-follow-recommendation-card__profile-link')]")`, you are getting a list of `WebElement` instances corresponding to profile links
- then, you are looping over these elements
- for the first element,

  - you first get the `href` attribute
  - call `arranging_items()` function
  - navigate to the profile link
- for the second element,

  - you get the `href` attribute value - but, wait, *you are not on the initial page anymore - you've already navigated to the first profile page*.

Instead, collect the links first and then navigate to them one by one:

```
links = [item.get_attribute("href") for item in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class,'feed-s-follow-recommendation-card__profile-link')]")]

for link in links:
    arranging_items(driver, link)
```

Comment: OMG!!!! What you did above just solves the problem in a minute. You are really the gem of a guy. Thanks sir, alecxe for your magical touch on my erroneous code.